# Quarkus startup warning

Tags: amazon-ecs, quarkus

I am running Quarkus 1.3.2.Final on Fargate using awsvpc as network mode.

When the container starts, I get the following messages:

```
2020-04-15 21:22:29,675 INFO [io.quarkus] (main) Installed features: [agroal, cdi, flyway, hibernate-orm, hibernate-validator, jdbc-postgresql, mutiny, narayana-jta, rest-client, resteasy, resteasy-jackson, resteasy-mutiny, scheduler, smallrye-health, smallrye-openapi]
2020-04-15 21:22:18,664 WARN [io.qua.net.run.NettyRecorder] (Thread-0) Localhost lookup took more than one second, you need to add a /etc/hosts entry to improve Quarkus startup time. On Windows the path is C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts. See https://thoeni.io/post/macos-sierra-java/ for macOS details.
```

How can I fix the warning related to the /etc/hosts file in a container in a cloud environment?

Comment: I have created https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/8822 to try and improve the situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My task definition was configured to use only 512MB of memory and 0.25vcpu. I increased the memory to 1024MB and the issue was fixed.